# How to Round image corners with BoxFit.contain in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout

My problem is when I wrap the image with a container that has a specific size and uses BoxFit.contain property for it will not round the image. checkout the below image: 
[image: image link]
I think the image cant round itself because it cants expand to fill container. I know that I can use BoxFit.cover but I want to use BoxFit.contain because I have limited space and images that can be of any sizes. my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            child: Image.network(
              'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

Comment: I didn't get it completely what your problem is. I got that you want to use Boxfit.container, but what does bother you exactly? The background of the container, the image size or something else?

Comment: @Iammuratc I want to clip my image, not container. the container added only to show I have limited space. I add ClipRrect as a parent to Image.network, but there is nothing happening to picture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to wrap your `ClipRRect` widget with `Center` or any `Align` widget.

Most of the widgets will try to fill its parent, if the parent doesn't specify any alignment property.

In your case the `ClipRRect` filled its parent `Container` (300x300) since the container doesn't specify any alignment to its child. And Image with `contain` property will try to maintain image ratio and being centered in `ClipRRect` widget. So It made `ClipRRect` corners invisible or no effect.

**Demo:** [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ffd9e1d7abead511a36647bbd5272090)

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("My image size"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: Center(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://mfiles.alphacoders.com/847/847991.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Edit:** Here I used `Center` widget. But you can also just simply specify alignment property in the `Container` widget.

Comment: thank you for your answer this is what I want and this will work correctly. can you explain to me why we should use align or center widget?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BoxFit.fill` if i understood correctly this is what you want to achieve :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My image size"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            child: Image.network(
              'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Put in a codepen demo](https://codepen.io/FirasDev/pen/ZEbqxqx)

**EDIT for a workaround to your question :**

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<Widget> getImage() async {
      final Completer<Widget> completer = Completer();

      final url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkd0a.png';
      final image = NetworkImage(url);
      final config = await image.obtainKey(const ImageConfiguration());
      final load = image.load(config);

      final listener = new ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, isSync) async {
        print(info.image.width);
        print(info.image.height);

        completer.complete(Container(
            child: Image(
          image: image,
          height: info.image.height.toDouble(),
          width: info.image.width.toDouble(),
        )));
      });

      load.addListener(listener);
      return completer.future;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My image size"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Widget>(
          future: getImage(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return snapshot.data;
            } else {
              return Text('LOADING...');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `BoxFit.fill` won't look good for vertical squared images like [image](https://mfiles.alphacoders.com/847/847991.jpg)

Comment: Then you use `BoxFit.cover` You can't have it both ways, you want to ignore the aspect ratio to fill your box, but you want to preserve the aspect ratio so that image still looks good. alternatively you can try a go around by using `ImageStreamListener` and adapting your box to the image size you get from `ImageInfo` check my edit if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the widget with a ClipOval with flutter.

Take a look at this doc : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html

Answer (score 0):

use stack for it

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
  ],
)
```

Here, I’m simply using a container with an image inside it

```
 Container(
      decoration: Box Decoration(
        image: Decoration Image(
          image: Asset Image('images/new_york.jpg'),
          fit: Box Fit . fit Height,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```