# Flutter: Image border with BoxFit.contain

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to wrap my image inside a container which has a `BoxDecoration` with a simple border. The image itself must have `BoxFit.contain` and I dont' know the dimensions of the container (imagine the SizedBox may have any possible size).

```
SizedBox(
  width: 750,
  height: 1400,
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
      ),
      child: Image.network(
        'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg',
        height: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=ab05e20bd52889d922d0815c1c6922d0)

The result looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is that the black border is exactly below the image. I already found a similar [question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847055/1640425) on SO but somehow it seems not to be applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it like this by adding boderRadius tou your container

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
 ),
```

however i recommend you you use this method cause it is more suitable

```
ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                                          child: Container(
                                            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width maxHeight: 500, minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,),
                                            child: FittedBox(
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,//use BoxFit.height of width depending on your layout to make your image more fitting 
                                              alignment: const FractionalOffset(0,.0),
                                              child: Image.network(
                                             'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg',
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BoxFit, try a Container, like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My image size"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          child: Image.network(
              'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I need the image to have `BoxFit.contain`. As soon as I set that property, your solution doesn't work anymore.